# c# Object class into XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm a little new to the Class object into XML file. 
I have a series of class
Classroom:

```
class ClassRoom
{
    private string m_sName = string.Empty;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return m_sName; }
        set { m_sName = value; }
    }

    private List<Student> students = null;
    public List<Student> Students
    {
        get { return students == null ? students = new List<Student>() : students; }
        set { students = value; }
    }

    private Teacher teacher = null;
    public Teacher TeaccherforClassroom
    {
        get { return teacher == null ? teacher = new Teacher() : teacher; }
        set { teacher = value; }
    }
    private Teacher subTeacher = null;
    public Teacher SubTeaccherforClassroom
    {
        get { return subTeacher == null ? subTeacher = new Teacher() : subTeacher; }
        set { subTeacher = value; }
    }

    internal class Student
    {
        private string name = string.Empty;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
    }

    internal class Teacher
    {
        private string name = string.Empty;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Also 
People

```
    class People
{
    private List<Person> person = null;
    public List<Person> Persons
    {
        get { return person == null ? person = new List<Person>() : person; }
        set { person = value; }
    }

    internal class Person
    {
        private string name = string.Empty;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
        private int age = 0;
        public int Age
        {
            get { return age; }
            set { age = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

I need something like this to translate into this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Class roomNumber="201" date="JANUARY 31, 2016">
  <ClassRoom Name="SCI101">
    <Students Name="Tom">
        <StudentNumber>545454</FundRiskMeasure>
    </Students>
    <Students Name="Jerry">
        <StudentNumber>123456</FundRiskMeasure>
    </Students>
    <TeaccherforClassroom>
        <Name>"Smith"</Name>
    </TeaccherforClassroom>
    <SubTeaccherforClassroom>
        <Name>"Johnny"</Name>
    </SubTeaccherforClassroom>
  </ClassRoom>
  <People>
    <Persons Series="Peter">
      <Age>22</Age>
    </Persons>
    <Persons Series="Jenny">
      <Age>21</Age>
    </Persons>
    <Persons Series="John">
      <Age>24</Age>
    </Persons>
  </People>
</Class>
```

I looked into XML serializable but it seems like my question is a bit more challenging because i could have a list of new objects within a class. For example the classroom has a list of students with their attributes. 
 I also have Name popping up within the Node `<Students Name="Tom">` or it might pop as an attribute

```
<TeaccherforClassroom>
    <Name>"Smith"</Name>
</TeaccherforClassroom>
```

I am just wondering if there is a simple way of converting these Object either using LINQ or a similar way rather than writing to XML using streamwriter for each class and creating it more "manually". Hope this is pretty explainable. 

Let me know if you need more information for the question that i am asking.

Also i'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Comment: serializing lists will get you into trouble automatically.

Comment: @rene sorry i was creating these classes so that i can just call the object without creating an instance of it. I can remove the static if necessary.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ Is there another solution in which i can go about?

Answer (score 0):

All members of your class are static, as far as I know there is no serializer that will serialize static classes / static properties. Maybe you should reconsider the static modifiers.
As a simple 1 liner solution you could use the System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer for simple serialization / deserialization (for non static classes / properties).

Comment: I can remove the static out of this. I didn't know it'll affect the XML serialization. I feed the data into these object so it doesn't really matter if they are static or not. Could you tell me how you'd go about this if they are not static.

Comment: Follow this tutorial https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815813 . Create an instance of ClassRoom (ex. classRoom )and than serialize it  System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(classRoom.GetType());
      x.Serialize(Console.Out, classRoom);